# VS 2010 VB.net create listbox as class

Tags: vb.net, onclick

I have a Form1 in this Form1 I have created basic Common Controls like a  listbox, a Combobox etc.

What I would like to do is to create a Button Click event that  will create a new set of all these "Common Controls" like a new Class item, so that they are created below the first set.

 
Before Button(Add new) is pressed

```
"Combobox1" "ListBox1" "Textbox1"
Button(Delete this Item)
```

After Button(Add new) is pressed 2 times in row:

```
Button(Add new)

"Combobox1" "ListBox1" "Textbox1"
Button(Delete this Item)

"Combobox2" "ListBox2" "Textbox2"
Button(Delete this Item)

"Combobox3" "ListBox3" "Textbox3"
Button(Delete this Item)
```

Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I will presume you are looking to learn vb.net, Here is a good article to start with

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_listbox.htm

the code for an event triggered by a button click is

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  MsgBox("You have clicked a button")
End Sub
```

Comment: No I'm not learning from scratch . I all ready have a lot of code but to make it more neat i'm rewriting it.

For example i now have 10 sets of these controls. To add 1 additional set so that total would be 11 I have to do it manually in code. So now I want to create a new class to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to create a brand new class that generates documents (stream writers if i remember correctly) and then record everything in strings, make sure to have loops, give input places so you actually can give an ID for each of these controls.

Comment: The problem is im storing information in SQL DB. So to add Stream Writers would be to add additional step. What i want is to do this in memory and when the form is closed it saves all field to SQL DB.